# Achieving a Github-like tooltip

Tags: javascript, html, tooltip

I'm trying to implement a tooltip, like GitHub avatar hover. When an avatar is mouseover (hover), a tooltip is presented over the avatar. For this, I'm using [popper.js](https://popper.js.org/).

```html
<!-- I'm using avatar to act as the container. -->
<!-- classes are omitted for simplicity. -->

<div id="avatar"">
   <span>DM</span>

  <!-- Hidden tooltip -->
  <div id="tooltip" class="hidden">
     <p>Show me when hovered</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```js
import { createPopper } from '@popperjs/core';

// Event function for mouseover when avatar is mouseovered

showTooltip = (e) => {
  
    let tooltip = document.getElementById('tooltip');
    let avatar = document.getElementById('avatar');
    tooltip.classList.remove('hidden')
   
   // Use popper to position the tooltip over the avatar
   createPopper(avatar, tooltip)

}
```

This works as expected. When I move the cursor over the `tooltip`, the `tooltip` is removed:

```js
let avatar = document.getElementById('avatar');
let tooltip = document.getElementById('tooltip');
avatar.addEventListener('mouseout', (e) => {
    if (!avatar.contains(e.target)) {
        // Hide tooltip
        tooltip.classList.add('hidden')
    }
})
```

The above would be ideal if I move my cursor left/right/bottom, away from the avatar. When I move the cursor up, into the tooltip container, the `tooltip` closes. I'm going "overkill" now:

```js
[..]
// yarn add debounce
import debounce from 'debounce';

[..]

avatar.addEventListener('mouseout', debounce(function(e) {
    if (!avatar.contains(e.target)) {
        // Hide tooltip
        tooltip.classList.add('hidden')
    }
}, 300));
```

My code looks messy as it is. How to achieve a Github-like tooltip, with "vanilla" JavaScript?

Comment: try `mouseleave` instead of `mouseout`. the event target for mouseout is the individual child of the container, while the mouseleave is invoked on the container element.